# How to hide/close other elements when new element is being opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ran into problem with creating custom select dropdown plugin in jQuery. I'm at the one-at-the-time-open feature. Meaning, that when you open a dropdown, then other(s) will close.
My first idea was to create some global array with all dropdowns in it as objects. Then in the "opening"-function, I would add the first line to first check that none of the dropdowns are open (if open, then close them.)

I created a very scaled version of my script: http://jsfiddle.net/ngGGy/1/
Idea would be to have only one dropdown open at the time. Meaning, that when you open one, other(s) must be closed, if not they will automatically close when a new one is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the `DropDownSelect`ized lists like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/ngGGy/3/.

```
(function($){
    var lists = $(); // cache of lists

    $.fn.DropDownSelect = function (settings) {
        jQuery.globalEval("var zindex = 100");

        var thiselement = $(this);
        var thislist = thiselement.next('ul');
        lists = lists.add(thislist); // add current one to cache

        thiselement.click(function () {
            lists.slideUp(); // hide all lists initially

            if (thislist.is(':visible')) {
                thislist.slideUp();
            } else {
                thislist.css('z-index', ++zindex).slideDown();
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Perfection in extreme short time (meaning I cant even accept it yet.) Extra-point question: Is it possible to group the dropdowns together and have different settings. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ngGGy/5/

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas: I hope this is what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/ngGGy/7/.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Basically, you solved it anyways and I can see the method. I meant that group1 can have multiple open and group2 will have only one at the time. But the grouping in generally was my issue, you solved it and adding different settings is no problem for me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Your dropdown set seems to behave like an accordion.

This is easier to accomplish if you wrap each dropdown in a div with a class, then use that to target all the dropdown uls you have.

I [forked your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzwHJ/1/) with a working example.

(**EDIT** updated fiddle link)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your forked fiddle is exactly the same as my original. However I do get your point. In the main script, I have #global_wrapper, that will go around then and I already tried the "currently-open"-class idea. It didn't work for some reasons. Also, for the higher goal of script being neater, I don't want to use the currently open class.

Comment: I forgot to click update on the fiddle and lost my changes, sorry! I [created a new one](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzwHJ/1/) (link above also updated). What I'm suggesting is a wrapper with class `dropdown` around each button div + ul pair. Then you could apply your plugin to that outer div, targeting the elements inside (instead of applying to the button div and targeting the ul as the next sibling). In other words, you isolate the HTML for each plugin instance inside a separate div.

Comment: Oh I see. Well this certainly is a simple fix. Works really nice. But, I cannot group them in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track, but if you're only going to have one dropdown list open at a time then you want them to be related somehow. Fortunately your markup is already there, so all we should have to do is modify the JS. I've updated your jsFiddle project here: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/ngGGy/4/

First the selector. jQuery will let you select attributes that are similar by using `^=` like this:

```
$('div[id^=button]').DropDownSelect();
```

Now we just have to update your plugin a bit. Notice that what used to be 'thislist' is now called 'everylist'. Now we can enforce that every list closes on click before opening the list associated with the button that was clicked.

```
(function($){            
    $.fn.DropDownSelect = function (settings) {
        jQuery.globalEval("var zindex = 100");

        var thiselement = $(this);
        var everylist = thiselement.next('ul');

        thiselement.click(function () {
            var thislist = $(this).next('ul');
            if (everylist.is(':visible')) {
                everylist.slideUp();
            }
            thislist.css('z-index', ++zindex).slideDown();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, calling them together with `$('div[id^=button]')` limits the plugins features. As I said its a scaled version. Also, my idea was one-at-the-time not one-always-open. Meaning, your script leaves the last open dropdown always open and when you close it, it will open again.

Comment: Also I think, if you have multiple dropdowns under one call, you must loop trough them inside the plugin: `return this.each(function() {});`

Comment: While I'll admit I misunderstood the parameters of your request, I think you'll find that the code does indeed work as expected without relying on any looping. Feel free to check out the jsFiddle project I linked to in my response: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/ngGGy/4/

Comment: Well, yes it does work without looping, however there is one else {} missing: http://jsfiddle.net/ngGGy/9/ This is how it should be.  Well in general, your answer deserves +1, since you created a very simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Why not raise an event that all drop-downs subscribe to. pass in the id (or instance) of the one currently being opened. In the handler check whether the handling instance is the one being opened. If not, close it.